# Do Shared Web Workers persist across a single page reload, link navigation

Tags: javascript, multithreading, html, websocket, web-worker

[Shared Web Workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#shared-workers-introduction) are designed to allow multiple pages from the same site (origin) to share a single Web Worker.

However, it's not clear to me from the spec (or other tutorials and information on Shared Workers) whether the Shared Worker will persist if you have only one window/tab from the site and you navigate to another page on the same site.

This would be most useful in the case of a WebSocket connection from the Shared Worker that stays connected as the site is navigated. For example, imagine a stock ticker or chat area that would persist (without having to reconnect the WebSocket) even while the site is navigated.

Comment: Currently storage event is your best option for that, shared workers maybe later...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125823/how-is-it-possible-to-share-single-js-resource-between-browser-tabs/19165781#19165781

Comment: Would wish for a updated 2023 answer that states if any new spec changes have involved, if any new browser currently support keeping shared worker alive durning page reload. think current answers are rather quite outdated - but it may still be valid and/or unchanged

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have done some testing to find out the answer to this in practice.

Firefox does not yet support creating WebSocket connections from Web Workers: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504553 So Firefox is not relevant until that bug is resolved.

IE 10 doesn't have [support for Shared Web Workers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sharedworkers) so it's not relevant either. So that leaves Chrome.

Here is an example to test shared web workers.

First the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <a href="shared.html">reload page</a>
    <script>
        var worker = new SharedWorker("shared.js");
        worker.port.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
            console.log("Got message: " + e.data);
        }, false);
        worker.port.start();
        worker.port.postMessage("start");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the implementation of the shared worker itself in `shared.js`:

```
var connections = 0;

self.addEventListener("connect", function(e) {
    var port = e.ports[0];
    connections ++;
    port.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        if (e.data === "start") {
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:6080");
            port.postMessage("started connection: " + connections);
        }
    }, false);
    port.start();
}, false);
```

Test results in Chrome 20 (**the answer**):

When the page is loaded simultaneously in two separate tabs, the connection count grows each time one of the pages is reloaded or the self-referential link is clicked.

If only a single instance of the page is loaded then the connection count never changes when the page is reloaded or the link is clicked.

So, in Chrome 20: **Shared Web Workers do not persist across page reloads and link navigation clicks**.

Comment: If I reload page or open a new one - SharedWorker will recreated? I write console.log(new Date().getTime()); And time always show different in console, after page reload. So always created a new WebSocket instance after page reloads, correct?

Answer (score 8):

It seems like this is basically the same problem as [the question 'What happens to an HTML5 web worker thread when the tab is closed while it's running?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875310/what-happens-to-an-html5-web-worker-thread-when-the-tab-is-closed-while-its-run).  I think the key part of the spec is [this statement](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#kill-a-worker):

> User agents may invoke the "kill a worker" processing model on a
>   worker at any time, e.g. in response to user requests, in response to
>   CPU quota management, or when a worker stops being an active needed
>   worker if the worker continues executing even after its closing flag
>   was set to true.

An '[active needed worker](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#active-needed-worker)' is defined as follows:

> A worker is said to be an active needed worker if any of the Document
>   objects in the worker's Documents are fully active.

So, as I understand it, if all the windows referencing a worker are closed then the browser is required by the spec to terminate the worker, but not immediately.  Depending on it persisting will therefore be unreliable even if it appears to work occasionally.

In your example my approach would be to load the whole site by Ajax - you're not going to be able to run the Web Workers if your users have JS disabled anyhow, then use the [History API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#the-history-interface) to make the user's page address correspond to the actual page (maintaining search engine and non-JS compatibility).

Comment: My question is whether the transition (link click) from one page to another on the *same site* (or a reload of the same site) moves the worker into a non-active needed state, and whether this will cause it to be killed. In other words, does it go from active to active or does it transition to non-active first before the next page loads (and if so is it a long enough period to matter)? This is really a question about what browsers actually do and what the intention is. The spec wording itself is ambiguous, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @kanaka Yes, unloading the page moves it to a state where it should be killed (see [step 5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#run-a-worker)), but the spec doesn't require it to be killed immediately.  As I said, it may work occasionally, but don't expect it to be reliable.  If you want to know what browsers actually do, try it.

Answer (score 6):

I have had success with a somewhat roundabout technique whereby when I want to go to the next page but maintain the SharedWorker, I open up a (hopefully unobtrusive) popup window that creates the same worker, wait for it to become active and send a message to the original port/window, which then navigates to the new page and then, when that page loads, closes the popup. This strategy maintains at least one active connection at all times, so the worker never decides to shut down.

This technique seems to be fairly robust so far. Although seeing the popup is somewhat annoying, it's a reasonable compromise for some use cases.

Comment: Can you show me your example please. I am always creating a new one even after page reload.