# Is HTML5 Web Workers for a page or across pages

Tags: multithreading, html, web-worker

I went through couple of articles that talk about Web Workers in HTML5 and I was not able to clearly understand the following:

- Is the life cycle for a web worker limited to a single page or across pages of an domain?
- Is the life cycle for a web worker persistant after a page is loaded?
- Are web workers a better option to using than an ajax call within setInterval?

Appreciate if someone could help me shed some light on the above questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do Shared Web Workers persist across a single page reload, link navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336774/do-shared-web-workers-persist-across-a-single-page-reload-link-navigation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Is the life cycle for a web worker limited to a single page or across pages of an domain?

> Dedicated worker is limited to a single page, while shared worker can be related to many webpages

- Is the life cycle for a web worker persistant after a page is loaded?

> It could be persistent if it has onmessage() defined, and it could also returns after execution, if I understand correctly. In spec it says: let that run until it either returns, fails to catch an exception, or gets prematurely aborted by the "kill a worker" or "terminate a worker"...

- Are web workers a better option to using than an ajax call within setInterval?

> It depends. You can't simply say it is better or not. At the moment Web worker is mainly used for offloading complex JavaScript algorithms to run in the background.