# How to resume Socket connection on another page?

Tags: php, node.js, session, socket.io

Hi i am creating a social networking site for my college. It is based on PHP.
To create websocket connection to retrieve notifications and set up chat system using node.js with connect and socket.io frameworks.

I started a socket connection on one page which i want to resume the same connection with same id on other pages served by web server.

And destroy the socket on logout and like with session in PHP.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: sir i have not written any code for implementing websockets using node.js in my application yet
But i was successfully able to create a chat room in another application
Problem is i have some 15 pages that user can access
if i create connect to socket on one page i have to resume that connection on another page without have to restarting the connection

Comment: and its not entirely based on node.js all the pages are served by PHP so i have a problem resuming the connection on to other pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain session when socket goes through handshake process.
By restoring session - you will restore related data to that session as well.
Do not store data related to user in socket object, and socket.id is not reliable for identification - only for connection.

Additionally you could store session data in redis and then collect it using PHP and node, in order to have one session data storage but with shared applications.

Comment: sir could you help me with code of how exactly would i be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Another topic with similar problem: [How to maintain a WebSockets connection between pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886910/how-to-maintain-a-websockets-connection-between-pages)

I'm currently working with same implemation and I did overcome this problem on the server side code having user class that have list of connections that belongs to that user. First client will connect to the server, after that client will register itself using username and given random hash(Extra security against phishing) and the server uses this information to determite who is this client.

And when logging out send destroy command also to websocket server so it knows to destroy this user from memory.

Comment: sir so is it mandatory to connect function to server on every page i have?

Comment: and any help with coding part?