# Socket.io keep the connection on client side when client refresh or open new page

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Have some way to keep the same socket.io connection on client side if user open a new page or refresh the page, maybe store the socket in session or it's impossible?

Comment: sorry i was having a problem cause every time the client connect to my socket.io he gets a new socket.id, and i wanna to identify that user to send a message to all open connections from that client only, so i search a little and i can solve my problem with socket.io rooms

Comment: That is correct.  Every new connection gets a new ID.  If you want a persistent reference to identify a user, you should use a cookie which is available in `socket.request.headers.cookie` at the time of the new connection and you can use socket.io middleware to set a cookie if one does not exist.  Or, you can use something like express-session for a more general lasting session and then get access to that from socket.io too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's impossible.  You cannot keep the same socket.io or webSocket client connection when the page is changed or refreshed.  The browser simply does not do that.  When a new page is loaded or the current page is refreshed, all resources from the previous page are closed and freed by the browser, including socket.io/webSocket connections.

So, your server has to expect a new socket.io connection from the newly loaded page. If you use cookies or a server-side session object, you can identify, on the server, when a connection is coming from a client that you have previously seen and the server can then act accordingly to realize that this is just a previous client reconnecting on a new page.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If you think this in err, then please post exactly how you keep a socket.io connection open while the host page is changed to some other page.

Comment: what about the following: store a cookie on the client and store on the server a list of clients objects that have ever connected to the app. at connection event of a client, check if the cookie value is set inside the browser and which of the previously connected clients is. This can be a problem for real-world implementations due to replay attacks, but depending on what the system is supposed to do, it still a viable solution. No?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo - Your cookie scheme is typically called a session and is how most servers track a client from one page to the next - that's what cookies are for.  It can be used for regular http requests or for incoming webSocket requests too (all webSocket connections start with an http request so they get cookies upon connection).  If you are using express with node.js, then there is the express-session module that does a lot of the session management work for you and creates a list of these sessions and automatically associated them with each incoming connection based on the cookie.

Comment: Downvotes because your answer wasn't what they wanted to hear apparently. +1

Answer (score 0):

It seems now that WebWorker are a more widespread  technology that it could be use to share websocket.

As explain in this article https://crossbario.com/blog/Websocket-Persistent-Connections/
Webworker are Javascript that is running outside the "thread of the page" and thus are not deleted on page change.
Note that it is running only in the same domain.
You can also look at Kanaka's answer here [How to maintain a WebSockets connection between pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886910/how-to-maintain-a-websockets-connection-between-pages) (2012-2017 answer beware)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (almost to not wast you time on it) if you do a F5 for example, because all of the javascript execution context objects will be reset.

But it's possible if you want to keep the socket connection alive between multiple tabs.

using the Broadcast Channel API it will help synchronize the socket connection
across multiple tabs, ensuring that the connection remains active.

When a socket connection is established in one tab, it will send a message through the
Broadcast Channel API to inform other tabs to establish their socket connections
as well. This allows the socket connection to be shared across multiple tabs and
stay alive as long as at least one tab remains open. (with the same origin).

first you need to create a service outside the react components. to keep the reference of the object.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import {BroadcastChannel} from 'broadcast-channel';

class SocketService {
  constructor() {
    this.socket = null;
    this.broadcastChannel = null;
    this.channelName = 'socketConnectionChannel';
  }

  initializeBroadcastChannel() {
    this.broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel(this.channelName);

    this.broadcastChannel?.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (event.data === 'connect') {
        this.connect();
      } else if (event.data === 'disconnect') {
        this.disconnect();
      }
    });
  }

  connect() {
    this.socket = io('your-socket-server-url');
    // Set up event listeners or any other necessary configuration
  }

  disconnect() {
    if (this.socket) {
      this.socket.disconnect();
      this.socket = null;
    }
  }

  sendBroadcastMessage(message) {
    if (this.broadcastChannel) {
      this.broadcastChannel?.postMessage(message);
    }
  }

  // Additional methods 'sending data'... etc.
}

export default new SocketService();
```

The usage within a react component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
// ther service we created
import socketService from './socketService';

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Initialize the Broadcast Channel
    socketService?.initializeBroadcastChannel();

    // Connect to the socket when the component mounts
    socketService?.connect();

    // Clean up the socket connection when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      socketService?.disconnect();
      socketService?.sendBroadcastMessage('disconnect');
    };
  }, []);

  // Render your component

  return <div>My Component</div>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Side Note:
If you want to maintain the socket connection without closing it during a page reload. you need to store the connection state on the server and resuming the connection when the page reloads.

but this approach will be on the backend and it's complex enough TO NOT WASET YOUR TIME ON IT

the behavior you observed where the socket connection is closed and reestablished upon page reload is normal. I would argue.