# Django Channels: How to keep socket alive

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to use django channels and templates to implement authentication. I know that there is an authentication section in the official website, but I have a question about the socket, which is created in the client side via templates.

From my understanding, django templates multi-page application, so if I create a socket in `login.html`, the socket will be disconnected in `main.html`, and I have seen it happen.

Is there a way to keep the socket alive even if I navigate to different pages?

Comment: This is a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886910/how-to-maintain-a-websockets-connection-between-pages

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep a socket alive between pages. `socket`'s connection is persistent until it is closed from either the client-side or server-side.

When you move from one page `login.html` to another `main.html`, the connection is closed and you need to reinstate it.

**the working model of a socket**:

**`Socket`** is a persistent connection where you are able to communicate in real-time.

**`Room`** consists of a set of **`Sockets`**.

When a **`Socket`** subscribes to a **`Room`**, it can listen to all the communication that is happening in that **`Room`**. i.e, when someone sends data in that room, it is received by all sockets listening to it.

So, you keep this **`Room`** details unique, eg: for `user1` you can have `room1`.
When `user1` tries to connect to server with a `socket1`, you authenticate him and subscribe/register his `socket1` to `room1`.

Similarly, when you change page to `main.html`, you create `socket2` and subscribe it to `room1` again based on user auth.