How to use a react context in astro island without re-rendering the provider
So I have two pages that want to share the same react context (QueryClientProvider in this case). The problem is that the only way I was able to achieve this leads to re-rendering of the context provider which is problematic, e.g. in cases of re-initializing websocket connection.
I've built a demo to demonstrate the issue.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-njjsdv-zcx9t1
Is there a way to transition between index and about page without re-rendering of the ContextWrapper?

Unless you use ViewTransitions, Astro is a MPA (multi-page-app) (see https://docs.astro.build/en/concepts/why-astro/#server-first and/or https://mb21.github.io/blog/2023/09/18/building-a-modern-website-ssg-vs-ssr-spa-vs-mpa-svelte-vs-solid.html#single-page-app-spa-vs-multi-page-app-mpa) Thus every page navigation will cause a new websocket connection (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886910/how-to-maintain-a-websockets-connection-between-pages). You should either reconsider whether you need a websocket, or transition to an SPA.
