# How to execute web worker task continuously even though the location url is redirect?

Tags: html, web-worker

I use [gifjs](https://github.com/jnordberg/gif.js) to generate a lot of gifs from png/jpg files once user logins success. At same time, I want to change the `location.url` to direct user to my website main page. But the problem is that the web worker task stopped once the url is changed. So how to execute web worker task continuously even though the location url is redirect?

Answer (score 0):

If the browser does a load of a new page, the short answer is that workers will be terminated. Definitely dedicated workers, and according to [Do Shared Web Workers persist across a single page reload, link navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9336774/1319998) shared workers (that aren't being used by other windows/tabs) will be too.

**But...**

If you didn't use any full page loads, and made the entire site use Javascript for navigation / posting of forms, and use the HTML history API to change the URL, then the worker will survive as the user logs in and navigates the site. The worker will only be terminated when they leave the site, or force a reload in the browser.

Depending on the current setup of your site, this might mean considerable change of both the browser and server architecture, the details of which I suspect are beyond the scope of this question.